# What should the bucket path be with a top hits

Tags: elasticsearch, path, bucket

I am trying to create a query in elasticsearch, which is able to retrieve the documents for each group, which is the latest document within each group and meet a specific criteria. But I have not been able to solve this one.

Say the following documents are indexed in myindex in elasticsearch:

```
POST /myindex/_bulk
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 1, "ident":"group1","version":1, "chdate": 1, "field1" : 1}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 2, "ident":"group1","version":2, "chdate": 2, "field1" : 0}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 3, "ident":"group1","version":2, "chdate": 3, "field1" : 1}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 4, "ident":"group1","version":2, "chdate": 4, "field1" : 0}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 5, "ident":"group1","version":3, "chdate": 1, "field1" : 0}
```

I would like to find all documents, which has field1 set to x if the document with the highest chdate, for each ident and version, which has field1 set to x.

In a case where x is 0 then the documents, which has objid 4 and 5 should be returned In a case where x is 1 then the documents, which has objid 1 should be returned

ChatGpt suggested this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ident": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ident"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "version": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "version"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_hits_agg": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "chdate": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "field1_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "hits": "top_hits_agg.hits.hits",
                  "field1": "top_hits_agg.hits.hits._source.field1"
                },
                "script": {
                  "source": "params.field1 == 0"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But elasticsearch comes out with following error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: No aggregation found for path [top_hits_agg.hits.hits._source.field1];"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: No aggregation found for path [top_hits_agg.hits.hits._source.field1];"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Anyone who knows what the bucket path should be in this case

Thanks in advance

Comment: if x is 0 then the documents, which has `objid` 2, 4 and 5 should return. Right ?

Comment: if x is 0 then document, which should be returned is 4 and 5.

The reason why 2 is not picked out is that the query (or at least it is supposed to) look at the highest chdate for each group. Where each group is ident and version

So for ident: group 1 and version 2, there will be three documents 2, 3, 4. Then it will select the one with the highest chdate which will be 4 (in this case it will have 4) and the n it will check if field1 is 0. which in this case is true.

Hopes that clarifies it

Comment: I have added a search query (based on your requirement) below, let me know if this query resolves your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [multi-terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html) and [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation to achieve your required result.

Multi Terms aggregation, will create unique buckets based on `version` and `ident`. Then top-hits bucket will retrieve the documents (based on the buckets created) having having highest `chdate`

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "field1": 0
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres_and_products": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [
          {
            "field": "version"
          },
          {
            "field": "ident.keyword"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "topHits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "chdate": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": "objid"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "genres_and_products": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": [
            2,
            "group1"
          ],
          "key_as_string": "2|group1",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "topHits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "75889252",
                  "_id": "gtowPIcBFkuh8-KNVHAi",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "objid": 4
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    4
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": [
            3,
            "group1"
          ],
          "key_as_string": "3|group1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "topHits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "75889252",
                  "_id": "g9owPIcBFkuh8-KNVHAi",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "objid": 5
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As shown in the result above, you will notice that the top hits aggregation buckets, give you your required result.

Comment: I tried to run the query as you suggested and it does indeed provide the right answer when field1 is 0, however it is wrong when field1 is 1. It will pick out the ones with objid 1 and 3. I would like it to be only 1, because the highest for version 2 is 4 and that is 0 and not 1.